# /dev/pve already exists on the filesystem

Tags: linux

I am reinstalling Proxmox 5.0 on Dell r410 servers and have taken hard disk drives from other servers into the r410. These drives were identified as foreign drives and had to clear their configurations to use them.

Now I am in trouble as I can install Proxmox as it says "unable to create volume group 'pve'.

The installation logs say that `/dev/pve` already exists. How do I overcome this issue and continue with the installation?

Answer (score 1):

Proxmox uses logical volume management (`lvm`) when installing the base application. This error means the hard disks you moved from the other server still have information regarding the previous `pve` logical volume group. To fix this you can use the `lvm` command line interface included with the proxmox installer.

1. First step is to make sure you choose debug mode from the proxmox installer menu
2. `cd` to `/sbin`
3. Use `lvm lvdisplay` to figure which logical volumes (lvs) you need to remove
4. Remove all pve associated logical volumes using the `lvremove` command e.g.

   ```
   lvm lvremove /dev/pve/root
   lvm lvremove data
   ```
5. Remove the pve volume group

   ```
   lvm vgremove pve
   ```
6. Type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> to return to the proxmox installer and finish the installation

A short tutorial on `lvm` can be found [under this link](https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/40702/how-to-manage-and-use-lvm-logical-volume-management-in-ubuntu/).